# HDD not found after battery reset. LiveCD detects HDD

Tags: boot, uefi, live-usb, ahci

I did a battery reset. But then BIOS cant find HDD, LiveCD does though.

**With Battery reset i mean**

1. Remove charger
2. Press battery reset-button with a needle for 30 seconds.
3. Attach charger. Wait 1 hour. Restart computer. Battery successfully reset.

**BIOS error**

Restarting computer throws error `All boot options are tried. Press <F4> key to recover with factory image using Recovery or any other keys for next boot loop iteration.`

- BIOS boot order shows only network cards.
- Same problem after changing AHCI
- Same problem after disable safe boot.
- Same problem after setting boot to UEFI

**Ubuntu LiveUSB works**

Listing harddrives from liveUSB shows correct `sda` and `sdb` disks. However, still no harddrives are found by BIOS after running boot-repair.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I changed to CSM instead of UEFI. (samsung 7-series BIOS says something about CSM is for windows.)

After that i rebooted into liveUSB and:

1. In [boot-repair]: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair , i ran MBR repair via advanced options.
2. Restarted and ran boot-repair again, with one error regarding blocksize.
3. Rebooted and everything worked.